# Firefox browser 20 support selenium-webdriver

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have Firefox browser v20 and I want to know which version of selenium-webdriver support to it.

Answer (score 2):

Use latest Selenium Webdriver 2.32.0.jar

You can download it from here. http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

You can view changelog in this link which states that it supports Firefox 20. http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG